# get some text inside of border (WPF)

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio

I have a border in my `WPF-Application` and I want to have some text inside of my border like in my picture below.

But I could not figure out how to do it.

My code right now:

```
<Border Margin="10" BorderThickness="5px" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
  <RadioButton Margin="5">Test</RadioButton>
</Border>
```

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Why not customize the border around a [GroupBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.groupbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), which already does this?

Comment: This is what I needed. I've searched and searched but could not find anything, This is the thing I've searched for all day. Thank You so much!!!

Comment: @B0BBY I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a GroupBox that meets your needs.

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox  Margin="10">
        <GroupBox.Header>
            Some Text
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="10" Text="Happy every day!"/>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

[image]